# what is better with jquerymobile dust or json2html?

Tags: jsontemplate

what is better with jquerymobile dust or json2html?
I'm working with a listview and my data is ported via ajax the application is on jquery mobile i need an easy template to represent the coming data in listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well since I wrote json2html I would go with that one ;) .. though it really depends on what you're trying to do with the templates.  The benefit with json2html is that you are using json for both the template AND the data instead of having the template as text/string also there isn't a need to compile the templates (which makes it easier to modify later).  As a side note we've heard of json2html being used in a number of jquerymobile projects without any issues.

If you are using it let us know!